# data accumulation from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

---

```
out_gate,in_gate,num_connection
a,b,1
a,b,3
b,a,2
b,c,4
c,a,5
c,b,5
c,b,3
c,a,4
```

shown above is a sample csv file.
First of all, My final goal is that the compile result becomes a table about number of connections between gates like below:

```
  a b c 
a 0 4 0 
b 2 0 4 
c 9 8 0
```

and Now I finished making a list of the first column(out_gate)
like this; `listfile = ['a','b','c']` and trying to match this each data `(a,b,c)` one by one to the in_gate 
so, for example when out_gate 'c'-> in_gate 'b', number of connections is 8 and
'c'->'a' becomes 9.

I can match out_blk and in_blk in a row with its connection numbers, but hard to accumulate the connection numbers of each out_gate

Is there any solution ?

Comment: I think you should take a look at pandas.

Comment: Agree with Jutorres, pandas is a good choice (see my solution below) because it is well tested, often well optimized, and deals nicely with missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Python you should look at the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for the input and a [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for collecting the totals:

```
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
with open('file.csv') as f:
    r = reader(f)
    next(r)  # skip headers
    for row in r:
        if len(row) >= 3:
            x, y, count = row
            d[x][y] += int(count)

keys = sorted(d)
for x in keys:
    print(' '.join(str(d[x][y]) for y in keys))

0 4 0
2 0 4
9 8 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! but I've just run the module you posted, 
there's an error saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test7.py", line 8, in <module>
    for x, y, count in r:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Is there any reason for this ?

thanks agian:)

Comment: There might be an empty line at the end of the file or some line that does not contain at least 2 commas. I added some sanity check there.

Comment: Thanks. by the way, What if My final goal changes into commas and strings as well just like the form of csv file?? (just like 4x4 matrix with commas and strings(a,b,c)) . I appreciate your answer but It still doesn't work when I use this way with 30 input gates and output gates. and I don't understand the meaning of the 9th line of your answer. Everything elses are fine.

and Is there any other way with using lists of colunmns and for loop?
(ex) list1=[a,b,c],list2=[b,b,a,c,a,b,b,a])
Hope it helps for others as well thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do this for large amounts of data, you should absolutely check out numpy and pandas, which both have more effective and natural methods of handling tables than native python.

In case you only need a solution right now, accumulations can be done straight forwardly in pure python with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

con = defaultdict(int)
for count, line in enumerate(connections):
    if count == 0:
        continue
    in_gate, out_gate, number = line.split(',')
    con[f"{in_gate}->{out_gate}"] += int(number)
```

Now you can access the entries the following way:

```
print(con['a->b'])
>> 4
print(con['a->c'])
>> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-line high-level answer via [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), if you do not wish to resort to line-by-line readers and defaultdict.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'b', 3], ['b', 'a', 2], ['b', 'c', 4],
                   ['c', 'a', 5], ['c', 'b', 5], ['c', 'b', 3], ['c', 'a', 4]],
                  columns=['out_gate', 'in_gate', 'num_connection'])

pd.pivot_table(df, index='out_gate', columns='in_gate', values='num_connection', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import csv
import itertools
data = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))
new_data = [b+[int(a)] for *b, a in data]
final_data = {tuple(a):sum(map(lambda x:x[-1], list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(new_data, key=lambda x:x[:2]), key=lambda x:x[:2])}
letters = sorted(set([i for b in final_data.keys() for i in b]))
matrix = '\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, [final_data.get((b, i), 0) for i in letters])) for b in letters])
```

Output:

```
0 4 0
2 0 4
9 8 0
```